# How to read multiple objects in java using ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Person implements Serializable
{
    String name;
    int age;
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Hello.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        System.out.println("Enter number of data:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        Person voter = new Person();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name:");
            voter.name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter age:");
            voter.age = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            oos.writeObject(voter);
        }
        oos.close();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Hello.txt"));
        Person buffer = null;
        while((buffer = (Person)ois.readObject())!=null)
        {
            if(buffer instanceof Person)
            {
                if(buffer.age<18)
                {
                    System.out.println(buffer.name+" is unable to vote.");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(buffer.name+" is able to vote.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write and read multiple objects into and from a txt file, the writing part works but the reading part doesn't.
Only the 1st object is read everyloop, how to read next object?

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3062)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1561)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
    at Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

Comment: You don’t check if your file is finished. You also only write a single object, which is why you only read one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have confused BufferedReader functionality with ObjectInputStream functionality.

[The documentation for BufferedReader.readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) says:

> **Returns:**
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached without reading any characters

However, the same is *not* true of ObjectInputStream.  It does not return null when the end of the stream has been reached.  There is, in fact, no built-in way to know when you are at the end of the stream;  you will have to take measures to signal the end.

Since you’re checking for null, the easiest thing to do is to write a `null` value yourself before closing the ObjectOutputStream:

```
oos.writeObject(null);
oos.close();
```

Side note: Be aware that writing the same Person object again and again may not do what you expect.  ObjectOutputStream keeps track of objects which have been previously written to the stream, so they aren’t repeated.  You can get around this in two ways:

- Move `Person voter = new Person();` *inside* the body of your for-loop, so a new Person object is written each time.
- Use [writeUnshared(voter)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared(java.lang.Object)) instead of writeObject.